# Is UITextField empty?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

To know if an UITextField is empty I used the following code:

```
if ( [ [textField text] isEqualToString:@""] )
```

But unfortunately it somehow fails to tell if the text field is empty.

What are the other ways?

When [textField text] is empty, it equals to nil.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? It always returns false?

Comment: No, sometimes [textField text] equals to nil. Why is that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Perhaps try `[[textField text] length] == 0`?

Comment: This works even if [textField text] is nil, since in Objective-C you always get 0 returned from a nil object.

Answer (score 7):

```
[textField hasText]
```

See [reference](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITextView/hasText).

Comment: What you are pointing me to is UITextView. And UITextField doesn't have this method. Unfortunately.

Comment: I already wondered why you named your variable textField while referencing to UITextView in the question title.

Comment: I edited the question to have UITextField instead of UITextView.

Comment: Not available in iOS 7